# C# Not recognizing resources, .NET to blame?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to build a C# Program (https://github.com/f1r3fr0st/ajart-studio-edit). First, I load the file but but it gives the error:

The C# project "Art Studio Edit" is targeting ".NETFramework, Version = v4.6.2", which is not installed on this machine. To proceed, select an option below.

Change the Target to .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Download the targeting pack for ".NETFramework, Version = v4.6.2".

When I choose to change the target, then attempt to build the project, I get a multitude of errors which claim that the resources were not able to be found (PcapDotNet, NAudio, AMF3SpecCli, etc.) even though they are all in the project's "Resources" section. Somehow, I have no idea how to replicate it, I was able to get most of the errors to dispensary, with AMF3SpecCli being the only one not to work. After a bit of research, I realized the .NET redirect could be the issue, but it seems like there is no way for me to install hte 4.6.2, which doesn't make sense. I tried downloading and installing 4.6.2, but it says it can't cause a newer version is installed, which doesn't make sense if VS tried to downgrade to 4.6.1... but then I looked and it seems the installed .NET frameworks are 3.5 and 4.8 - so where is the 4.6.1 coming from? And how do I install 4.6.2? Is that even the issue? Please help if possible!

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies (the NuGet packages) work with 4.6.2, not 4.6.1. This leaves you two choices.

1. Find the versions that work with 4.6.1 and update the references to those versions.
2. CORRECTION: Install the targeting pack for 4.6.2.

Of the two, the 2nd is easier, but the first will give you some experience cleaning up .NET references (and still may not work if the authors of the github project used something from 4.6.2 that does not work in 4.6.1).

Do you want to fix it or learn?

EDIT: BTW, you can end up with some of the same fun updating to the very latest. Then you have to see if you can get all of the NuGet packages updated. This is actually a useful exercise as senior developers and architects often spend time fixing NuGet messes in code. Going back to the past or forward, either will get you some experience in this.

SECOND EDIT: If you want some real-world experience, update the project for the latest, if possible. I say "if possible" as it may use other projects that are not updated. Then see if you can contribute to the open-source project an updated version. You both help the open-source community and learn a valuable set of skills.

Comment: I tried to install 4.6.2. It wouldn't let me saying there was a newer version already installed.

Comment: Also, on the .NET Website, it says you "can't install earlier versions of .NET v4 since (insert reason here)

Comment: You need the targeting pack for 4.6.2, not the runtime.

Comment: It didn't work. I installed the 4.6.2 .NET, it no longer promps to redirect, but I have the same errors - The type or namespace (insert all of the resources) could not be found. What else is wrong?